# Eliminating the mobile break point in BootStrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am finishing up redesigning my website and incorporating Bootstrap into it. I realized that I have a mobile website from a 3rd party so I don't need the XS break point.

I have tried to just display: none and use the hidden-xs class for everything that that falls below the SM break point but I would rather just have my website be at the tablet size no matter how small you resize the window.

How would I go about eliminating that XS break point? Does anyone have any suggestions?

Please let me know! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way to accomplish this is to either customize your own Bootstrap build or use LESS to make the change yourself.

To customize your own build (http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints), change the @screen-xs breakpoint value to "768px" so it matches the @screen-sm-min value.

Alternatively, override the @screen-xs variable in your LESS file by setting it to @screen-sm-min, like so:

```
@screen-xs: @screen-sm-min;
```

Note that @screen-xs is deprecated as of Bootstrap v3.0.1.

Comment: Thank you I will try and utilize the link you gave me.